# apt-get error kills my bash function

Tags: apt-get, bash

I'm trying to write a simple function for my .bashrc, to simplify a common issue I have:

```
$ sudo apt-get install nltk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nltk
$ apt-cache search nltk
python-nltk - Python libraries for natural language processing
$ sudo apt-get install python-nltk
```

So I wrote this:

```
function sagi(){
    sudo apt-get install $1 || apt-cache search $1
}
```

But no matter what I do, after the `apt-get install` part runs and errors out because it can't find the package I asked for, the function exits completely.  I even tried doing this:

```
function sagi(){
    sudo apt-get install $1
    echo $1
}
```

Again, nothing after the failed apt-get runs.  Strangely enough, when I run:

```
$ sudo apt-get install nltk || apt-cache search nltk
```

(at the bash prompt) everything works as expected.  What am I doing wrong?

---

Edit: The function is at the end of my .bashrc file, and is shown in its entirety above.  I checked, and my .bashrc doesn't use `set` anywhere. (I initially suspected that `set -e` might be the culprit).  No traps, either, and the error code from $? is 100.

Comment: Some questions: What is the error code returned from the your script when it is failing (echo $?)? Does your script have traps set? Are you using the set command anywhere in your script?

Comment: Works perfectly for me tho. What distro are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 10.10, with GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: Does your `~/.bashrc` source any other files that may be affecting this? Have you checked your `/etc/profile` and `/etc/bash.bashrc` (or similar) in case they are being run (for a login shell)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not really a solution but an improvement suggestion.

```
function sagi() {
  sudo apt-get -qq --dry-run install $1
  if [ $? == 100 ]; then
    sudo apt-cache search $1
  else
    sudo apt-get install $1
  fi
}
```

This would get you a cleaner and more secure way to do what you want. At first it checks if that package is in the repositories by performing a dry run first. After that it checks whether the error code is 100 (failed due to package not found) and invoking a cache search if so else it just installs the package.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still not sure why my old version didn't work, but I agree that this is much better.

Comment: @perimosocordiae: Hold on I'm checking your version on 10.10 in a second. EDIT: interestingly it works just find on my 10.10 installation too. Can't tell what is wrong. Sorry.